# Dual vector spaces and space of real valued 3rd-degree polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the answer of this question but it came as a tricky riddle to me.
Good question to test your understanding of linear algebra.

Take linear space of all 3rd-degree polynomials. The dimension is easily proved to be 3.
Now These are real valued functions on R.
Recalling the definition of dual space of R(also something about real valued functions on R), is space of 3rd-degree polynomials a subspace of dual of R?? (dimension of dual of R is 1.)

Comment: The duel space is the set of all linear functions from the vector space to the base field. The duel space is always isomorphic to the vector space when it is finite dimensional.

Comment: The dual space of $\Bbb{R}$ consist, indeed, of real valued functions on $\Bbb{R}$, but only the **linear** ones. A polynomial function (which is not the same as a polynomial) is not necessarily linear: Consider $f$ given by $f(t)=t^2$. And one more thing, the set of all degree $3$ polynomials is not a linear space (e.g. $x^3$ and $-x^3+x^2$ both have degree $3$, but not its sum). The set of all polynomials with degree *less than or equal* to $3$ **is** a linear space, with dimension $4$ (a basis is $1,x,x^2$ and $x^3$).